# How to forward port in AWS Application load balancer (ALB) port forwarding

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to have an application running on an EC2 instance and have a load balancer listen on port 80 but proxy it to the instances port 8080?

I cannot seem to get this to work. What setting to I need to change. I am running the cluster behind an application load balancer.

Comment: Yes, use ALB instead of ELB classic. ALB gives you the flexibility to use extra ports on the backend services.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Adding answer with AWS management snippets .

Add the instance port in the target group, refer below image for it. for example i've added tomcat 8080 port to the target group port/

[image]

Make sure that your ELB is internet facing. refer below image of ELB summary , which says that my ELB is internet -facing. and check that your routing is properly added.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks much for above clear explanation, but for me it's not worked. My configuration is, installed Apache Solr service in Private EC2 and trying to configure Apache Solr service with internal ALB(not internet-facing). Only when i append port in ELB URL then only able to access. internal-solr-elb-714176139.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com:8983/…  as you know i need to access ELB without port to work with Route53

Answer (score 24):

You define the instance port in the Target Group. You need to configure the Target Group to use port 8080. Then point the Application Load Balancer's port 80 listener to the Target Group. The ALB will listen on port 80, and forward requests to port 8080 on the Target Group instances.

Comment: Hi @Mark - can you please let me know what rules should I write in ALB to forward to PORT 3000? My React app is running on PORT 80, where as NODE JS API is running on PORT 3000. I want to run NODE JS API from my domain like - https://www dot mydomain dot com/api:3000

Comment: @SachinVairagi please don't add your question to other people's questions like this. Please post a separate question including what you have tried, and what issues you are encountering.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is definitely possible to use the Application Load Balancer (ALB) for port-forwarding.
As described in the other posts, you need to define both ends and connect them:

1. In the ALB listener, set the incoming port (usually 80 for HTTP or 443 for HTTPS)
2. Create a target group and set the target instance and the port that is served from there (in this case 8080)
3. Associate the listener with the target group

Also make sure that the **security group**, which is set for the load balancer, is not blocking any of the incoming or outgoing ports. (This is what caught me and why I added this additional answer.)