# How to access jenkins dashboard on webbrowser in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I am very new to AWS and Devops part, I read some official documentation and I installed Jenkins server in my ec2-instance it's successfully installed and it's running also ,when i try to open by using http://my-public-ip:8080 it's not opening. How to open my Jenkins dashboard in my web browser?

[image: This is my Jenkins server status]

This is my EC2 instance inbound rules:

[image: This is Ec2 instance inbound rules]

When I am trying to search in my browser it's showing some thing like this:

```
This site can't be reached13.235.67.157 took too long to respond.

Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest go to your security group of this instance which is **launch-wizard-5**  Edit it and You have to choose "Custom TCP rule"

Then you will be able to add the port to 8080

- Wait for second
- and open http://my-public-ip:8080 in your favorite browser
- You'll able to access your Jenkins GUI
  [image: This is how to add port]

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins uses a specific port: 8080

To verify this, inside of your jenkins shell try this:

try with `netstat -plnt`.

and

```
curl localhost:8080 -v
```

If you have a valid response showing you that 8080 port is online, your jenkin is ready to use. Just configure the 8080 port in your [AWS inbound rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26339070/3957754). Finally you will be able to access with:

**http://my-public-ip:8080**

If you achieve that, your next goal must be to **hide** the 8080 port. For that you could use the [ELB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42433553/3957754) to assign a custom domain if you have someone.

Comment: < HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Date: Fri, 30 Jul 2021 04:25:02 GMT
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID.a3d32962=node01xomm08zuv52uz07sepp9we4o1.node0; Path=/; HttpOnly
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< X-Hudson: 1.395
< X-Jenkins: 2.304
< X-Jenkins-Session: b4395941
< Content-Length: 541
< Server: Jetty(9.4.42.v20210604)
i am getting like this when i run curl cmd

Comment: #1 8080 port?  #2 refresh the page, I updated it!

Answer (score 0):

Add security groups

```
ALLTraffic
0.0.0.0/0
```

Then refresh the page